# Can i have a text field/dropdown list?

Tags: jquery, html

There is a common autocomplete that will dropdown results that seem to match whay you are asking such as google searches auto complete. I want a slight deviation to this. I want a select> such as:

```
<select>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
</select>
```

but no autocomplete, instead when one of these options is selected, you can alter the contents. So if you have volvo selected you can chang it to audi.

BTW: i previously posted an unclear question similar to this but deleted because of they unclairty. Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 0):

You might me interested in this: http://www.picnet.com.au/resources/tablefilter/demo.htm

Its under **MIT** license & open source project. Hope this helps!